# How can I prove that this sentence is valid?

Tags: first-order-logic

I am trying to prove the validity of the following: $$(\exists x Px\to \forall y Qy) \to \forall z (Pz \to Qz)$$ but I am completely stumped. Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: I've tried using deduction so that we have $$(\exists x Px\to \forall y Qy) \vdash \forall z (Pz \to Qz)$$ and then deduction and generalization to get $$Pz ; (\exists x Px\to \forall y Qy) \vdash Qz.$$ I don't see where to go from here.

Comment: Is it enough to give an explanation of why the formula is always true?  Or do you want a line-by-line formal proof?  I think the latter will be very hard...

Comment: There is supposed to be a line by line formal proof. The question asks to either "show there is a deduction" or provide a counter-model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Natural Deduction](http://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) :

1) $∃xPx→∀yQy$ --- premise [a]

2) $Pz$ --- premise [b]

3) $∃zPz$ --- from 2) by $∃$-intro

4) $∀yQy$ --- from 1) and 3) by $\to$-elim

5) $Qz$ --- from 4) by $∀$-elim

6) $Pz→Qz$ --- from 2) and 5) by $\to$-intro, discharging [b]

7) $∀z(Pz→Qz)$ --- from 6) by $∀$-intro.

Thus, from 1) and 7):

> $(∃xPx→∀yQy) \to ∀z(Pz→Qz)$ --- by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

---

We can also easily prove the *validity* of the formula in a "semantical way".

For contradiction, assume that $∃xPx→∀yQy$ is *true* while $∀z(Pz→Qz)$ is *false*.

Thus, for some $a$: $Pa→Qa$ is *false*, i.e. $Pa$ is *true* and $Qa$ is *false*.

But if $∃xPx→∀yQy$ is *true*, then either $∃xPx$ is *false* or $∀yQy$ is *true*.

In the first case we have a contradiction with $Pa$ *true* and in the second case we have a contradiction with $Qa$ *false*.